# Is there an equivalent on Windows to the DiskArbitration framework on Mac OS?

Tags: c#, winapi, diskarbitration

I'm looking into writing a tool that mounts certain external disks as read-only when they are plugged-in to the machine.  On MacOS, this was quite trivial with the Disk Arbitration framework.  It sends out notifications from the OS when a new drive is attached to a machine and allows you to veto, accept, or change mounting options (such as forcing the mount as read-only, etc.)  Is there any equivalent to this in Windows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent. For security reasons, Windows doesn't give user-mode code quite that much control (e.g., consider a virus deciding to stop you from mounting any disk it's suspicious might contain an anti-virus program).

The [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431.aspx) message notifies user-mode applications of things as they happen, but it's pretty limited -- in particular, while you can veto *removal* of a device, you're not allowed much (any?) control over addition of a device.

You can also use [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431.aspx) for more complete information, but I don't believe it gives you the control you're looking for either.

At least as far as I know, .NET doesn't support `RegisterDeviceNotification` directly, so if you want to use it from C#, you'd probably have to do it via P/Invoke.

For more control over devices being mounted and unmounted, you'd have to write some kernel-mode code, but at least from the sound of things that may be a bit beyond what you're interested in considering, at least for the moment.

Comment: That's what I feared.  We're definitely not looking into getting into kernel level code for this.  Thanks for the info.